# Oracle SQL MAX function not returning max on VARCHAR to NUMBER conversion

Tags: sql, oracle

I am attempting to get the highest system number from a set of rows. The system number is preceded with `SYS`, thus `select SYSTEM_ID from TABLE` would yield, `{SYS901,SYS87,SYS3024.....}`

This is the query I'm attempting to use:

`select MAX(REPLACE(SYSTEM_ID,'SYS','')) from TABLE`

The possible results are

`{901,87,3024,20,1}`

It is returning the `901` value where I'm expecting to see the `3024` value. I assume the problem is that the field is a `VARCHAR` not a `NUMBER`. How to address this problem, I do not know.

Comment: Removed `sql-server` tag - this question is about **Oracle** - not (Microsoft) SQL Server .....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
select MAX(TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(SYSTEM_ID,'SYS',''))) from TABLE;
```

Use TO_NUMBER to convert VARCHAR2 to NUMBER otherwise Oracle compares strings using their ASCII codes ('9' > '3')

Answer (score 6):

Of course it is returning the max.  It is just returning the max according to the rules of string comparisons, not numbers.

To get the numeric max, do a conversion:

```
select MAX(TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(SYSTEM_ID, 'SYS', ''))) from TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider doing a "safe" number conversion in case you have values in your table like 'SYS5001B':

```
SELECT MAX( TO_NUMBER( COALESCE( REGEXP_SUBSTR( system_id, '\d+' ), '0' ) ) )
  FROM table
```